# Arcobjects 10.6.1 dll register failed

Tags: .net, arcmap, arcobjects

I have created a ArcMap add-in button and failed in the dll registration. I got Visual Studio 2017, .Net framework 4.62, ArcMap 10.61.1 and ArcObject SDK 10.6.1 installed. The add-in and the dll files were built successfully.

The error message "Registration failed. Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.Addin, Version=10.6.0.0 or or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Appreciate your advice.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a test to work around, use the base command template to create a new project in VS. I can register the dll file successfully. The reason is I don't use this program as a button to run, but to run it as a command item in vba.

Paul